# Add python modules to cython for use in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cython, .so, cythonize

I am currently trying to write a plugin backend in c by using .so files. Doing this in c works as I expect it to. However I thought about writing python plugins for my backend. Here is when i stumbled upon cython which seems to be very promising.
My backend is calling a function within the .so files and expects a value in return.

This function currently looks like this:

```
cdef public size_t transform_data(char *plugin_arguments, char **buffer):
  printf("Entered function\n")
  print("test\n")
  printf("Test passed\n")
  return 5
```

The interesting part is, that the printf works just fine. However the print doesn't. I suspect this is because there is some sort of linking error to a python module that I am missing? Also later on I would like to be able to add any python module to that file, for example the influxdb module. A call to influxdb.InfluxDBClient doesn't work either right now, I guess for the same reason that the print is not working.

I am compiling the file using

```
cythonize -3b some_plugin.pyx
```

and I have also tried to compile using a setup file that looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("some_plugin.pyx"))
```

both resulting to a segfault as soon as I hit the print call.

Here is the code that I am using to call the .so file:

```
#include "execute_plugin.h"

#include <Python.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

size_t execute_plugin(char file_name[FILE_NAME_SIZE], char *plugin_arguments,
                      char **output_buffer) {
  if (!Py_IsInitialized()) {
    Py_SetPythonHome(L"/home/flo/.local/lib/python3.8");
    Py_SetPath(L"/usr/lib/python3.8");
    Py_Initialize();
  }

  if (!Py_IsInitialized())
    return 0;

  void *plugin;
  size_t (*func_transform_data)(char *plugin_arguments, char **output_buffer);
  char path[PATH_SIZE];
  if (!get_path_to_file(path, PATH_SIZE)) {
    printf("Could not receive the correct path to the plugin %s\n", file_name);
    return 0;
  }
  plugin = dlopen(path, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
  if (!plugin) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load %s\n", file_name);
    return 0;
  }

  func_transform_data =
      (size_t(*)(char *plugin_arguments, char **output_buffer))dlsym(
          plugin, "transform_data");
  if (!func_transform_data) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
    dlclose(plugin);
    return 0;
  }

  size_t length = func_transform_data(plugin_arguments, output_buffer);

  printf("Size of answer is %ld\n", length);

  dlclose(plugin);

  Py_Finalize();

  return length;
}
```

I have tried using the documentation and just copied the example: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html
In this example I didn't use an .so file but the .c and .h file that is also getting generated by the cythonize command. Interestingly enough the print function is working but as soon as I try to add another module like the influxdb module and try to call a function from it I also get errors.

Since I have not found a lot about using cython code in c I am wondering if what I am trying to do is even possible or if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be certain what your issue is because you don't actually show how you call your Cython function. So what follows is a guess.

Cython does not produce standalone C functions. It produces functions that are part of a Python module and require that module to be initialized. What is probably happening is that Cython caches the lookup to the global `print` function as part of the module initialization. Since you skip the initialization the cached `print` function is not set up (hence the crash).

When you read the documentation, you'd have seen that all the examples (["Using Cython declarations from C"](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c) and ["Embedding Cython modules..."](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html)) import the module before using it. You **must** do this. The preferred way to do this is with `PyImport_AppendInittab()`.

A second possibility is that you haven't initialized the Python interpreter. Again, this is not optional.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the code that is calling the Cython function. Indeed I did not use the PyImport_AppendInittab(). I will have a look into adding that.
But in the case where I copied the documentation (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html) the PyImport_AppendInittab() function got executed tho. Does that mean, that I have to execute the function for every module that I am using within my .so?

Comment: No, just modules that you're using outside of the normal Python import mechanism. I don't know how you combine it with `dlopen` though I'm afraid. Also, many Python modules (especially Numpy) don't work when you finalize and reinitialise the interpreter, so hopefully you're only doing that once